# WebDriver can't run tests on Firefox 4 and higher

Tags: java, gwt, selenium, webdriver, gxt

Recently I am facing a strange problem. I am using WebDriver for test automation for GWT web application.  (It's Maven 3 project) I am performing tests only for Firefox browser. Everything works fine as long as I use Firefox 3.6

Problems start whenever I try to run tests with newer version of Firefox starting from FF4 to FF8. Whenever i run my tests all I get is element not found exception for everything I try to locate, click, read etc. 
Any kind of searching using different kinds of locators (id, classname, name) results in:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"SOME_ID"}; duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
...
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

What is more it happens just with my application because when I wrote a quick test that goes to google.com and searches for some stuff everything worked well.

Has anyone faced similar problem? Is there something wrong with my webapp? Maybe I should change something somewhere? I just don't know what and where? Maybe some gwt app profile is needed for newer firefox?
If it is any help here's my POM file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>WebTests</groupId>
<artifactId>WebTests</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<!--START:repositories -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>selenium-repository</id>
        <url>http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/repository/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<!--END:repositories -->

<!--START:dependencies -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0</version>
        <type>POM</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.concordion</groupId>
        <artifactId>concordion</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.concordion</groupId>
        <artifactId>concordion-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<!--END:dependencies -->
```

Comment: did you try with selenium-java 2.16.0 ?

Comment: It is probably a coincidence, but a previous version of Selenium RC (not sure until which version) supported up to Firefox 3.6.

Comment: Unfortunately still the same.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem in our project, also using Maven etc as you are.

I tried several Firefox versions, but it seems even the latest version of selenium does not support Firefox beyond version 3.x

We just installed version 3.x on our integration server and we live with it.

Comment: Thx for the answer, it seems not only I have this issue

Answer (score 0):

When you update firefox, maybe there was a change in names of functions or classes which you forgot to change.

Did you try your code on google Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to **update to newer Selenium** - because of tight browser integration WebDriver is sensitive to changes in ABI.

Comment: What exactly should I update? I tried my code also with 2.16.1 version of selenium. I think it's the newest one? 
Still the same. 
Can you provide me with a sample POM file that works for you?

Comment: OK, so you updated - I saw 2.13 in your pom. I don't have access to my example now. Are you sure ID's in you application did not change ? Did you try to run Firefox with Firebug, put the app into some long wait and checked the DOM ?

Comment: Well i tried it again today and now even on google site i get permanently NoSuchElementException. Very simple codeSnippet:

    @Test
    public void shouldOpenGoogle() {
        WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
        webDriver.get("http://www.google.com");

        webDriver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        webDriver.findElement(By.id("searchText")).sendKeys("asd");
        
    }

Answer (score 0):

I tried again a little bit different approach. Yet still it is the same, page gets launched just fine and whenever i try to locate any element it fails with nosuchelementexception. It is the same on Firefox 4.0 and higher and also the same on IE 7,8.

Well I guess that I'll just go back to 3.6 and live with it :)